# How to hide a few divs in turn?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example,
I have about 200 divs on my website:

```
<div>LINK</div>
<div>LINK</div>
.....
<div>LINK</div>
```

I will click the links in each div in turn and I would like to hide and I would like to hide every clicked div. How to do this?

Comment: Typically, javascript

Comment: You only want to hide `clicked div` or all `divs`?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to employ javascript. Arguably the most popular approach would be to use jQuery with corresponding code along the lines of:

```
$("#link").click(function(){
 $(this).parent("div").hide();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
div>LINK</div>
<div>LINK</div>
.....
<div>LINK</div>
```

**js**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").on('click',function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery function `hide()` like this.

**Exp:**

```js
$("div").on('click',function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="link">LINK</div>
<div id="link">LINK</div>
.....
<div id="link">LINK</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by passing the event from the onclick function on the div itself, which basically tells the function who is caller and has info of the div upon which click event was triggered.

Since you will know the div/link where click was triggered, you can simply change its css style display to none. See example :

```
<div onclick="hideDiv(event)">
        <a href="#">Some link</a>
</div>
    
<script>
        function hideDiv(event) {
            // Get the clicked element from the event object
            var clickedDiv = event.target;
            
            // Hide the clicked div
            clickedDiv.style.display = 'none';
        }
</script>
```